# Android Studio Profiler Showing Garbage values

Tags: android-studio, android-profiler, android-studio-bumblebee

I'm trying to see the response but,not able to see because Garbage values are coming.Please refer the link for screenshot.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WX2v8.png

Comment: It looks like the same issue as https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/217765670. According the issuetracker, it has been fixed.

Comment: It has been fixed